# Ionic : How can I send a "Push Notification" on device without prompting notification itself?

Tags: android, ios, node.js, push-notification, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic Push Notifications, they are work properly:

1) Device receives notification if app is in background or is not running

2) App receive the notification data (not the notification alert) if the app is in foreground and use that data to make changes.

But I have another case and I am looking for its solution:
3) Device should not receive prompt if it is in background or is not running But device should receive data only(not notification prompt) if it is in foreground.

I am sending notification from nodejs server:

```
             var data = {
                "tokens":tokens,
                "notification":{
                     "alert":"MESSAGE",
                    "ios":{
                      "badge":1,

                      "expiry": 1423238641,
                      "priority": 10,
                      "contentAvailable": 1,
                      "payload":{
                        "key1":"value",
                        "key2":"value"
                      }
                    },
                     "android":{
                          "collapseKey":"foo",
                          "delayWhileIdle":true,
                          "timeToLive":300,
                          "payload":{
                            "key1":"value",
                            "key2":"value"
                          }
                        }
                    }
                }
        var dataString = JSON.stringify(data);
        var headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-Ionic-Application-Id': 'APP_ID',
            'Authorization' : 'KEY_HERE'
        };
        var options = {
            url: 'https://push.ionic.io/api/v1/push',
            headers: headers,
            method: 'post',
            body: dataString
        };
        function callback(error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log(body);
            }else{
                console.log(body);
            }
        }
        request(options, callback);
```

Comment: I was having a same issue,what i did was sending a extra flag in my payload.On the basis of which i differentiated.Dont know much is this relevant to you.

Comment: @NitishAgarwal Thanks for the response. But can you please explain me how can I stop the Notification prompt by evaluating the payload flag? Because we can access payload flag after the notification is received (prompted) and I want it before the prompt so that I can check if I want to prompt the notification or not.